# UIView animation disturbs the constraints

Tags: objective-c

I have set constraints at my .xib file , when i animate my textfield with keyboard, it looks good , later when I tried to set default positions that alignment was not good , that constraints are disturbed , What can I do ?

Thank you

Comment: Don't animate the view, animate the constraints.